# How Ruby Interprets $(foo)

Tags: ruby

When I read `RbConfig::CONFIG['libdir']` it gives me lib folder location. But in rbconfig.rb file `CONFIG["libdir"] = "$(exec_prefix)/lib"`. How the value is interpreted here.

Comment: Braces in question title and body do not mach. Where are the correct ones?

Comment: I am sorry @AlexeyShein. I updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(exec_prefix)` refers to a key in `RbConfig::CONFIG`.

But that's not a Ruby feature. `rbconfig.rb` contains [code to expand these values](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_3/tool/mkconfig.rb#L240-L260): every occurrence of `$(key)` is replaced with the corresponding value of `RbConfig::CONFIG['key']`

My `rbconfig.rb` contains these lines:

```
CONFIG["prefix"]      = (TOPDIR || DESTDIR + "/Users/sos/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2")
CONFIG["exec_prefix"] = "$(prefix)"
CONFIG["libdir"]      = "$(exec_prefix)/lib"
```

And their values are:

```
RbConfig::CONFIG["prefix"]      #=> "/Users/sos/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2"
RbConfig::CONFIG["exec_prefix"] #=> "/Users/sos/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2"
RbConfig::CONFIG["libdir"]      #=> "/Users/sos/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib"
```

Comment: Great answer! I've removed my answer since yours is the obviously more correct.

Comment: Can you clarify this. From where these values are getting loaded to $(key)

Comment: @Vijay Same way as anything mini-templating works--the link Stefan provides shows *exactly* how it works.

Comment: @Vijay the values come from `RbConfig::CONFIG`. More precisely, `gsub` finds the substring `"$(exec_prefix)"` and replaces it with `RbConfig::CONFIG["exec_prefix"]`

Comment: What i meant is mkconfig.rb is Ruby source package folder, But rbconfig.rb is located in ruby installed location. So how does it expands when i execute this `RbConfig::CONFIG['libdir']' in IRB.

Comment: I can understand this replaces that key with value. But from where it knows that value.

Comment: @Vijay not sure if I understand your question. `CONFIG.each_value` is a loop that traverses each value in the `CONFIG` hash, replacing the `$(...)` placeholders with their respective values. The replacement-values are also stored in the `CONFIG` hash.

Comment: In `irb` you can run `RbConfig::CONFIG["libdir"]`  will give you this value `/Users/sos/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib`. How it knows `$(exec_prefix)` is `/Users/sos/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2`.

Comment: @Vijay because `RbConfig::CONFIG["exec_prefix"]` is `"/Users/sos/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2"`

Comment: @Stefan  Could the have used `"#{CONFIG['prefix']}"` in place of `$(prefix)`?  It seems some kind of trick to save typing some chars.  Just wondering  :-)

Comment: @Stefan Now edit the value like this `CONFIG["prefix"]      = (TOPDIR || DESTDIR + "/Users/sos/.rubies/ruby-2.2.3")` and run this line of code `RbConfig::CONFIG["libdir"]`. You will get still `/Users/sos/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib`. Sorry for late  reply.

Comment: @Vijay that's because `TOPDIR` is already defined, so that the right-hand side of `||` is not evaluated. But if you edit `rbconfig.rb` and set `TOPDIR = 'foo'` (line 9), then `RbConfig::CONFIG["libdir"]` will actually return `"foo/lib"`

Comment: @WandMaker yes, you could probably do the same with string interpolation.